# rotate border with image

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have an image that is rotating 180 degrees and I want to put a border around it. The problem is when I do the border stays in the same place while the image rotates. How do I make the border rotate along with the image? I'll use a hand analogy to demonstrate the rotation of the image :
 ** with left hand **
starting point- hand is in front of you with palms facing you.
when the mouse hovers image- turn hand 180 degree until you see your knuckles.
when mouse leaves the image- hand turns 180 degree until you can see your palm again.

As stated before how do I make the pictures border rotate along with the image?

Comment: can you post your code or upload it on a fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=oFe2ejHDOb

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rotateY()` on you image hover:

DEMO

```css
img {
  border: 5px solid black;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
```